Jmeter giving incomplete json response
When i make get call in jmeter
i'm getting incomplete json response.
i have six json object in my response
but when i hit api with jmeter it giving me only 4 json object
but when i hit with postman, i'm getting 6 json object which i correct.
Response from jmeter
[
{
"clientId": "eiS5JSBddm77GnMFSLS4AueT2ZoIdwbE",
"hpId": "CPSTDHPID-40685E2",
"orderId": "CPSTDDEV2406134531E2",
"subcriptionId": 344406,
"emailId": "e2gekko_cpstd_dev@yopmail.com",
"mhEventsUUID": "c2db1982-82f6-4c4b-a40a-796b5d44d2a9",
"eventType": "GekkoAnnualAutoRenew",
"status": "SENT"
},
{
"clientId": "eiS5JSBddm77GnMFSLS4AueT2ZoIdwbE",
"hpId": "CPSTDHPID-40685E2",
"orderId": "CPSTDDEV2406134531E2",
"subcriptionId": 344406,
"emailId": "e2gekko_cpstd_dev@yopmail.com",
"mhEventsUUID": "697766c3-8e9b-4827-8321-4916ff606319",
"eventType": "GekkoPayDue10Day",
"status": "SENT"
},
{
"clientId": "LoL7IoAx4eBD1vV3avWBqbtyN3M4VDv1",
"hpId": "CPSTDHPID-40685E2",
"orderId": "CPSTDDEV2406134531E2",
"subcriptionId": 344406,
"emailId": "e2gekko_cpstd_dev@yopmail.com",
"mhEventsUUID": "0e2b3e5f-3f83-4383-b4f4-0029a5e8d99c",
"eventType": "GekkoWelcome",
"status": "SENT"
}
]
and response from postman
[
{
"clientId": "eiS5JSBddm77GnMFSLS4AueT2ZoIdwbE",
"emailId": "e2gekko_cpstd_dev@yopmail.com",
"subcriptionId": 344406,
"orderId": "CPSTDDEV2406134531E2",
"status": "SENT",
"hpId": "CPSTDHPID-40685E2",
"eventType": "GekkoPayMethodUpdateFailed",
"mhEventsUUID": "0a43c72b-a74d-4eaf-8741-3935fa92d172"
},
{
"clientId": "eiS5JSBddm77GnMFSLS4AueT2ZoIdwbE",
"emailId": "e2gekko_cpstd_dev@yopmail.com",
"subcriptionId": 344406,
"orderId": "CPSTDDEV2406134531E2",
"status": "SENT",
"hpId": "CPSTDHPID-40685E2",
"eventType": "GekkoPayFailed",
"mhEventsUUID": "529d4bc8-22c8-4722-8f13-f3c09e910f06"
},
{
"clientId": "eiS5JSBddm77GnMFSLS4AueT2ZoIdwbE",
"emailId": "e2gekko_cpstd_dev@yopmail.com",
"subcriptionId": 344406,
"orderId": "CPSTDDEV2406134531E2",
"status": "SENT",
"hpId": "CPSTDHPID-40685E2",
"eventType": "GekkoRefundNDays",
"mhEventsUUID": "19a8852e-a775-4c41-87be-1143c8377a4a"
},
{
"clientId": "eiS5JSBddm77GnMFSLS4AueT2ZoIdwbE",
"emailId": "e2gekko_cpstd_dev@yopmail.com",
"subcriptionId": 344406,
"orderId": "CPSTDDEV2406134531E2",
"status": "SENT",
"hpId": "CPSTDHPID-40685E2",
"eventType": "GekkoAnnualAutoRenew",
"mhEventsUUID": "c2db1982-82f6-4c4b-a40a-796b5d44d2a9"
},
{
"clientId": "eiS5JSBddm77GnMFSLS4AueT2ZoIdwbE",
"emailId": "e2gekko_cpstd_dev@yopmail.com",
"subcriptionId": 344406,
"orderId": "CPSTDDEV2406134531E2",
"status": "SENT",
"hpId": "CPSTDHPID-40685E2",
"eventType": "GekkoPayDue10Day",
"mhEventsUUID": "697766c3-8e9b-4827-8321-4916ff606319"
},
{
"clientId": "LoL7IoAx4eBD1vV3avWBqbtyN3M4VDv1",
"emailId": "e2gekko_cpstd_dev@yopmail.com",
"subcriptionId": 344406,
"orderId": "CPSTDDEV2406134531E2",
"status": "SENT",
"hpId": "CPSTDHPID-40685E2",
"eventType": "GekkoWelcome",
"mhEventsUUID": "0e2b3e5f-3f83-4383-b4f4-0029a5e8d99c"
}
]
i have added retry mechinsam for ther intveval of 1 minute
also added flow break for 2 min
and also added timeouts for http samplers



I think you're sending not the same requests, double check the requests configuration in JMeter and in Postman and pay attention to pretty much everything:

URL
Query String
HTTP Headers
etc.

Once you amend JMeter's configuration in order to send the same request as Postman does - you will see the same response.
Be aware that it is also possible to just record the request from Postman using JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder, for this you will need to:

Import JMeter's certificate into Postman
Configure Postman to use JMeter as the proxy

More information: How to Convert Your Postman API Tests to JMeter for Scaling

I'm using the same request
because the same URL I'm taking from jmeter and using in Postman and getting the correct response

found this fix
In the retry mechanism, I have to add more wait time before I exit the loop.
